# Does wxWidgets provide Search/Filter Dropdown?

Tags: wxwidgets

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_dropdown.asp) is a demo of Search/Filter Dropdown. I'm wondering if wxWidgets provides this UI widget.

At this moment, the closest I get is `wxOwnerDrawnComboBox`, but it doesn't show the dropdown until we press Alt-down on it.

A Search/Filter Dropdown is supposed to show (and update) its dropdown while the user is typing.

Assume we have a `wxOwnerDrawnComboBox` named X, and its data member `m_text` which is a `wxTextCtrl`. If we call X's method `Popup` to show its popup/dropdown when X's `wxEVT_TEXT` occurs, `m_text` will lose the keyboard focus to the popup. The user can no longer input in `m_text`. If we call `m_text->SetFocus();` in the `wxEVT_TEXT` callback to force the keyboard focus to go back to `m_text`, it goes even worse: Everything looks frozen, until the user presses double Esc and a runtime-error occurs:

> src/common/popupcmn.cpp(313): assert "!m_handlerFocus || !m_handlerFocus->GetNextHandler()" failed in Popup().

Any suggestion? Does wxWidgets provide Search/Filter Dropdown? If "no", is there a 3rd-party Search/Filter Dropdown widget? If "no" again, which direction to implement it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing exactly like this in wxWidgets. You could use [wxSearchCtrl](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2.0/classwx_search_ctrl.html) with some extra control or you could use [wxTextCtrl::AutoComplete()](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2.0/classwx_text_entry.html#ad911d59d6b381a20b0a6c34df2ac1d9f) to use the platform native auto-completion support, but if you want to have something exactly like your demo, you would indeed need to implement it yourself.

And yes, basing your implementation on `wxOwnerDrawnComboBox` should work, you may just need to use `CallAfter()` to avoid focus-related problems. But it's impossible to be sure without seeing your code in details.